# C: Efficient way to read two files from the command line

Tags: c

I'm sort of new to learning the C language and need help reading more than 1 file from the command line after the code has been compiled using gcc. For example if my code is compiled and the output is a.out it should be run like `a.out FILEA FILEB` so far this is what I have but when i try to add another loop to read another file `FILEB` i get segmentation fault, where is this error coming from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>

void evalFile(char *s);
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  FILE *fp1, *fp2;
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    printf("./progName fileName1.csv fileName2.txt");
  }

  fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp1) != NULL)
  {
     if(buffer[0] == "#")
        continue;
     evalFile(buffer);
  }
}

void evalFile(char *s)
{
  char *token, *del="(,)";
  token = strtok(s, del);
  while(token != NULL)
  {
    token = strtok(NULL, del);
  }
}
```

Comment: You miss 2 returns in your `main`. One `return 0;` at the very end, another `return -1;` at the end of the first `if` block that checks whether there has been correct amount of arguments passed.

Comment: I've never seen the notation `char *del(,);` before. Can you explain it?

Comment: You also miss checks on whether the files have been successfully opened or not.

Comment: I also don't see where `buffer` gets defined. This suggests you need to read [how to create an MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: we can not advice you do not post the code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
fp1 = fopen(argc[1], "r");
fp2 = fopen(argc[2], "r");
```

Your command-line params are stored in ***argv***, not ***argc***!
They are very different.

You want

```
fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // argv, not argc
fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");  // argv, not argc
```

Comment: these are typos I should have copied and pasted my program instead of typing the whole thing here

Answer (score 1):

you've got:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv)
```

`argv` is an array of char pointers, in your case it is just a single char pointer. change it to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

also, you've got a typo - there's no such C function `frets`. you mean`fgets`.

function prototype:

```
evalFile(char *s);
```

should have `void` in front. `void evalFile(char *s);` 
what is this - `*del(,);` ? i suppose you wanted do declare a delimiter, that will be used with `strtok`. change it to `char* del = ",";` 
`buffer` variable is not defined. you are reading strings with `fgets` to nowhere. 
you want to compare single charaters in your while loop. change

```
if(buffer[0] == "#")
```

to

```
if(buffer[0] == '#')
```

Comment: Sorry about the typos I was using my iPad to write this and autocorrect was not working with me.